# Select * from table_name is running slow

Tags: oracle12c

The table contains around 700 000 data. Is there any way to make the query run faster?

This table is stored on a server.

I have tried to run the query by taking the specific columns.

Comment: Does the table have any indexes? are you using filters, what's the complexity of your query?

Comment: What is the actual query you're running?  How big is the table?  What does "slow" mean? How long does it take?

Comment: Your table has 7 liters of data? (Lakh is unit that is not used outside of India and possibly neighboring countries.)

Comment: Q: Does the table have any indexes. A: Yes, Table contains 7 indexes. Q: Are you using filters. A: No, I am not using filters. Whats the complexity of the query. A: Cost: 4442 Cardinality : 896245.

Comment: Q: What is the actual query you are running? A: Select * from table_name. Q: How big is the table? A: rows: 896245 and total columns: 32. Q: What does "slow" mean? A: To fetch all data it takes 19 mins.

Comment: Q: Your table has 7 liters of data? A: No the table contains exactly 896245    nos of data.

Answer (score 0):

If `select * from table_name` is unusually slow, check for these things:

1. **Network speed.**  How large is the data and how fast is your network?  For large queries you may want to think about your data in bytes instead of rows.  Run `select bytes/1024/1024/1024 gb from dba_segments where segment_name = 'TABLE_NAME';` and compare that with your network speed.
2. **Row fetch size.**  If the application or IDE is fetching one-row-at-a-time, each row has a large overhead with network lag.  You may need to increase that setting.
3. **Empty segment.** In a few weird cases the table's segment size can increase and never shrink.  For example, if the table used to have billions of rows, and they were deleted but not truncated, the space would not be released.  Then a `select * from table_name` may need to read a lot of empty extents to get to the real data.  If the GB size from the above query seems too large, run `alter table table_name move;` to rebuild the table and possible save space.
4. **Recursive query.**  A query that simple almost couldn't have a bad execution plan.  It's possible, but rate, for a recursive query has a bad execution plan.  While the query is running, look at `select * from gv$sql where users_executing > 0;`.  There might be a data dictionary query that's really slow and needs to be tuned.

Comment: Thank you sir. This helped me a lot.